# Clustering geographical data in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R and  would like to cluster geographical information using k-medoids. While accounting for curvature of the earth, I need to cluster on latitude, longitude, and depth.

My ultimate goal is to plot the colored data as a map.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33204379/clustering-earth-data-using-k-medoids-in-r. I cannot mark it as dupe, as the other question doesn't have answer.

Comment: Oh thanks! I'll be sure to follow that one